Replace on autocomplete selected
Is it possible to configure Notepad++ to replace certain words after we select them from the autocomplete dropdown.
For instance, I have made a user defined language and in that xml file have entered the list of autocomplete sentences. All these sentences start with text_
So I want to replace the text_ after the user has selected the option from the autocomplete dropdown.
I have appended the text_ since notepad++ only does a word prefix kind of autocomplete.
Do we receive any events on autocomplete menu closed or selected...
Can this be done with a plugin perhaps if not possible in vanilla notepad++... Pythonscript maybe...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
